# Does a sticky note application that sticks to the front of the screen exist?

Tags: windows, note-taking

I need to make use of Sticky Notes app that acts like a traditional post-it notes (and not a program with that name but is like a normal windows program).
However, I discovered all the sticky note programs are just sticky notes in look but not in use, as they don't stick.

I need a sticky note program that sticks to the front of the screen. If a window moves over the sticky notes the sticky note must not disappear behind it. If the sticky note does disappear then it's not a sticky note. It is a normal window.

Software I tried

- Windows 10's default sticky notes.
- Sticky notes (Classic)
- Evernote sticky notes
- Simple sticky notes
- Stickies
- Stickypad
- Others

I have downloaded and tested so many sticky programs and none of them stick. I am starting to think that lack of any is that 3M patented post-it notes functionality to force people to buy their post-it notes to stick on computer screens.

Googling "sticky notes don't stick" doesn't bring up anything useful

Is there any solution?

Only workaround I tried is to use [WindowTop](https://github.com/gileli121/WindowTop) but the full version is paid and uses more CPU resources than my liking.

Comment: I use Stickies myself and it does support always on top, on a per-note basis. Disabled by default, but you can easily pin it to prevent them being covered by other windows.

Comment: @Alejandro, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

[Simply Sticky Notes](https://www.simplestickynotes.com/) and [Stickypad](https://www.greeneclipse.com/stickypad.html) have options to stay on top always.

These options are not enabled by default so you must enable them.

Answer (score 0):

Notezilla does this. Its free to try for 30 days and it costs $29 to buy. You can stick it to any window. Its the only one I found that does this.